# Vega-Lite: Enable Autosizing for Faceted Plot

Tags: visualization, vega-lite, vega

I would like to set the width of a faceted plot dependent on the size of my window (I'm using the Vega-Lite plot in Kibana).

This would be a minimal example:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category":"A", "group": "x", "value":0.1},
      {"category":"A", "group": "y", "value":0.6},
      {"category":"A", "group": "z", "value":0.9},
      {"category":"B", "group": "x", "value":0.7},
      {"category":"B", "group": "y", "value":0.2},
      {"category":"B", "group": "z", "value":1.1},
      {"category":"C", "group": "x", "value":0.6},
      {"category":"C", "group": "y", "value":0.1},
      {"category":"D", "group": "x", "value":0.2},
      {"category":"D", "group": "y", "value":0.3}
    ]
  },
  "facet": {"field" : "category", "type": "nominal"},
  "columns": 2,
  "spec":{
    "width": 200,
    "encoding": {
      "x":{"field": "value", "type":"quantitative"},
      "y":{"field": "group",
      "axis":{"labels":false, "ticks": false, "title":null}}
    },
    "layer": [{
        "mark" : "bar",
        "encoding": {"color": {"field" : "group"}}
    }]
  },
  "resolve": { "scale": {"y": "independent"}},
  "config": {
    "view": {"stroke":"transparent"},
    "facet": {"spacing": 10}
  }
}
```

I know from the [documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/size.html), that you cannot set width to 'container' for faceted plots but is there really no way to set the size dynamically?

My current workaround it to use vega instead of vega-lite, where you can compute the size as a signal:

```
"signals": [{ 
      "name": "width","value": 500,
      "on": [ { 
        "events": { "source": "window", "type": "resize" }, 
        "update": "containerSize()[0]" 
      } ] 
    },
    {"name": "number_of_culumns", "value": 2},
    {"name": "child_width", "update": "width/number_of_culumns"}
}]
...
...
"width": {"signal": "child_width"}
```

But vega is so much more complicated to work with compared to vega-lite. Is there no way to do something similar in vega-lite? I tried to use parameters (which seem to be the equivalent to vega's signals), but I was not able to set the width to a param, unfortunately.

Any help would be very welcome...